# PHP - Validate the recaptcha v2 response

Tags: php, forms, validation, recaptcha

```
#form.php

if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
    $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $captcha=$_GET["g-recaptcha-response"];
    $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=__1234__&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

    echo $response;
```

Returns:

> Notice: Undefined index: g-recaptcha-response in /var/www/clients/qmax/app/controllers/job_application_controller.php on line 114 { "success": false, "error-codes": [ "missing-input-response" ] }

```
echo $response->success;
```

Returns:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/clients/qmax/app/controllers/job_application_controller.php on line 119

I just need to get the "success" object, then I can test if it is True OR False and I am done.

Comment: try `var_dump($_POST)` check if the key value you are seeking exists

Comment: echo $response;

returns { "success": false, "error-codes": [ "missing-input-response" ] }

so the string is empty making the response false. I need to get the "success" value.

Comment: this is not the defult provided by google php libairy, have you tried that

Comment: recaptcha v2 does not provide a php lib that I know about...???

Comment: you shouldn't post your secret on the internet btw

Comment: Please note that you've included your secret key in the question. Please don't do that again

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
$captcha = $_GET["g-recaptcha-response"];
```

Then you need to decode the json by Google like so:

```
$g_response = json_decode($response);
```

Then just check with if/else:

```
if ($g_response->success === true) echo "success!";
```

Comment: If you're validating a recaptcha response, keep in mind you should be using a POST request instead of a GET request as per Google's api spec. In practice it might not matter since this is a one time code and you don't have to worry about it leaking out to other websites using the referer header or showing up in a server's server logs.